# Is it compulsory that URL and folder name are same

Tags: php, apache

Is it compulsory that URL and folder name are same. If not I have a folder say temp and I want URL is like `http://www.test.com/te*&mp`

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The mod_rewrite is for that purpose which shows virtual paths as like folders. There are number of tutorials to following. Also note that you can change your file extension or remove also in the URL path through this. Also this makes easy for users and search engine rankings.

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache's [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to redirect requests made to `te&mp` to the proper `temp` folder. You won't be able to use `*` as it isn't an allowed character for a file name (Windows, it is allowed on a POSIX system).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^te&mp/(.*) temp/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also note that since [`&` is a reserved character](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), you'll need to URL encode it (`te%26mp`).

Comment: Since when is `*` not allowed in file names? I can do `touch \*` without problems. Whether this is a good idea is a different question altogether.

Comment: This is not working I did as you said and access my page as http://www.test.com/te%26mp but page not found error is their

Comment: @tdammers: It depends on the platform. It is restricted in Windows, not in a POSIX compliant system.

Comment: @Abhijeet: Does your Apache configuration has `mod_rewrite` enabled and is its use restricted by `AllowOverride` ?

Comment: I was assuming a POSIX-like system, which is the most common choice to run Apache.

Comment: @Andrew Moore what is syntax of it can you please write it for me

Comment: @Abhijeet: The syntax for what exactly?

Comment: @Andrew Moore: It is still not clear to me do i write AllowOverride in plase of RewriteRule

Comment: @Abhijeet: No, `AllowOverride` is a server directive which must be placed in the `<Directory>` note of your server's `httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read on [htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) and [URL Rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. See the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive.